# Why Ionic3 live-reload updates are taking too much time?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When I used Ionic 1 with AngularJS and made some change in HTML the web page was reloaded very fast, something like 0.5 seconds.
And when changed the CSS changes took affect even without reloading anything and by zero time.

When doing the same thing with Ionic3 + Angular 4,
it takes something like 5-7 seconds for a blank app:

```
ionic start myapp blank
```

And then:

```
ionic serve
```

Then change something, even just adding `p` tag and wait as I mentioned.

Is there a fix for this, is this due Angular2+ or due to Ionic 3?

Thanks.